# I want to watch a log file

Tags: shell, watch

I am running stuff on a server, and I find `watch -n 30 qstat job.pbs` a bit uninformative. Why can't I get

```
$ watch -n 30 less location/of/log|tail
```

to work? I get a blinking cursor. I do get output from

```
less location/of/log|tail
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `tail -f log.txt`  The -f option is designed to do exactly that: Every time the file is updated, it displays the addition.

Answer (score 1):

I find `less` is more convenient if you want more than just following a log file (e.g., scrolling and searching etc.).
E.g. open log file with `less` as follows:

```bash
less /path/to/log
```

then press

`Shift+F` - to follow the log (behaves just like `tail -f`)

`Ctrl+C` - to stop following the log

`?pattern` - to search backward in log file